# rvm install error running 'requirements_osx_port_install_port'

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems, terminal, rvm

Im trying to install rvm on my machine and select a version but im getting this horrible error can anybody help? I need to install dandelion deploy but cannot due to this problem.

```
Error running 'requirements_osx_port_install_port',
please read /Users/mariovassiliades/.rvm/log/ruby-2.0.0-p0/1368093119_port_install.log
```

Comment: had to update my xcode DUH

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I solved this problem by install "**Homebrew**" first :

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/go/install)"
```

after that I run: `$ brew doctor`, then it tell me:

Warning: No developer tools installed.
You should install the Command Line Tools.
Run `xcode-select --install` to install them.

so i run "**xcode-select --install**" ,after that i run " **rvm requirements** ", it works!

P.S.: If you get **Error: No available formula for gcc46 /**, try **brew tap --repair homebrew/dupes** , then try reinstalling. By the way, I use **brew install gcc46**, it took me more than half an hour without any prompt。

In the end, excuse me for my poor english。

Answer (score 5):

You've probably not done the following : After installing xcode, launch it, navigate to Xcode->Preferences, Downloads tab. Install Command Line Tools. This will download and install C, compiler, loader and other command line utilities needed to compile & build the Ruby packages.

Answer (score 3):

It's also possible that you've got a Beta version of Xcode installed as the active version along side of a production version (e.g. XCode 5 vs. XCode 4.5).

To switch versions do the following:

```
sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/
```

Comment: Lifesaver! thanks alot. I can confirm this is indeed an issue.. Had both XCode 5 Beta and XCode 5 regular on my system, and had to switch it over like this.

Answer (score 0):

my issues was helped using inaircastle solution. note the url needs install on the end >> 
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go/install)"